# Converting .py to .exe & script failed to execute error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am currently coding a game in python using pygame. I wanted to convert the game to a .exe to be able to share it with my class and this is my first time using auto-py-to-exe and I am not sure how to deal with this error. I followed the instructions and converted my .py file to a .exe file. When I opened the directory to run the executable, a window pops up and says "failed to execute script Game" (i called the scrip Game). Could someone please help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: i do believe you would have been able to run the application with Python command line. But will be in a better position to understand and give in insights as what is it you tried to execute as a command and what failed / errors if specified. This will allow others to understand where to pinpoint issue and come back with better solution.

Comment: Try to use pyinstaller to create executable file(.exe), Copy and paste all the assets(image, map...etc) in executable(.exe) directory (Inside Dist folder).